# Variable with several instances from array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net module for analyzing data.

First I set up a new variable with

```
Dim EE As New EEPROM(Buff, 128)
```

EEPROM is defined as

```
Public Sub New(ByVal EEPROM_() As Byte, ByVal BytesCount_ As UInt16)
```

within the Class EEPROM.
Buff is 1D byte array.

Now I have more data and Buff is 2D array.

Is there any possibility to use the given module as far as possible by e.g. transforming the 2D to a list??

Comment: The class is what it is. If it's your class then change it. If it's not you can't.

Comment: Do you have the code for `EEPROM`?  You could overload the constructor.

Comment: You could have a `List(Of EEPROM)`.

Comment: Seems to be the best approach so far. I will use that for my solution.